# Unable to save/modify imported build definition in VSTS

Tags: build, azure-devops, build-definition

I am attempting to export a build from one project to another. Projects are in different collections. I have collection admin so perms should be good, but just to be sure I granted myself build and project admin.

I exported the build as json using the VSTS UI in the source project then imported in the target project. All the tasks are present, but the parameters are grayed out. I also cannot enable/disable tasks. There are some parameters that need to be filled in such as build agent. I was able to select the appropriate agent. I have no outstanding items at this point that the UI is indicating I would need to address prior to saving. The save, discard, queue options are all grayed out.

I can add a new phase, but I can't add any tasks to that phase. I also tried bringing up the yaml and compared it to the yaml in the source project, no differences.

Why can't I save my imported build definition?

Comment: Does the build defined you exported can save/modify? And can you show the exported json file here?

Comment: Hi Marina. I was able to get the import to save. I had to modify the json and convert all references from the old collection and project. Is this to be expected? I would have thought the import process would have handled this.

Comment: All the configurations of the imported build defintion are same as the comfigurations of the exported build definition. If you want to change the build repository or tasks etc, you need to change to manually as what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import succeeded after replacing all instances of the project and collection ids in the json I was attempting to import. At the time of this post those changes must be completed manually.

UPDATE:

I tried just removing the offending properties rather than replacing them and that worked. I created a simple script to clear out those properties:

```
Param(
[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[alias("p")]
$path
)

$removeProperties = @("triggers","metrics","_links","authoredBy","queue","project")
$json = Get-Content -Path $path -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($property in $removeProperties) {
  $json.PSObject.Properties.Remove($property)
}

$json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Set-Content -Path $path -Force
```